# Command to get the service status of macOS

Tags: linux, macos, service, status

Here is the command to get the service status on Linux:

> `service ${services} status`

I want the command to get the service status on macOS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You only are able to list the services:

```
sudo launchctl list
```

Mix it with some grep and you have it.

```
sudo launchctl list | grep service <-- Here you put the service you're looking for
```

The output has the following meaning:

- First number is the PID of the process, if it's running, if it isn't running, it shows a '-'.
- Second number is the exit code of the process, if it has finished. If it's negative, it's the number of the kill signal.
- The third column is the process name.

Comment: Can you pls give the full code with grep. That would be more helpful.

Comment: I have mixed it with grep command, but I got some integer values (mostly zeros ) in the status field. How can I be assure that service is running or stopped.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As you said pid shows '-' is stopped service and the services that have integer pid is in running state. Is that correct.

Answer (score 6):

Simple `brew services list` will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

You can try this.

```
brew services info service_name
```

E.g., I'd like to know RabbitMQ state

```
brew services info rabbitmq
```

It will show like this:
[Service info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXDPB.png)

Comment: That is, only if you use homebrew